# Does Contents.m support folders?

Tags: matlab

I have been learning using Contents.m to add comments

```
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-a-help-summary-contents-m.html
```

My code base has the following hierarchy

```
+foo
   Contents.m         
   +bar
      a.m
      b.m
      Contents.m
```

The Contents.m in +foo is

```
% +FOO
%
% DIRS
%   +bar - abcdef
```

Note that Contents File Report tool ignores sub-folders. So I added the line +bar manually.

The Contents.m in +bar is

```
% +BAR  qqqq
%
% FILE
%   a.m - comments1
%   b.m - comments2
```

When I do

```
help +foo
```

I got

```
+FOO

DIRS
  +bar - abcdef
```

Here, the +bar is a link. After I clicked it, I have

```
+foo

DIRS
  +bar - abcdef

+bar qqqq
FILES
   a.m - comments1
   b.m - comments2

+bar qqqq
FILES
   a.m - comments1
   b.m - comments2
```

Note that the '+bar qqqq' section appears twice. The same thing happens if I do 'doc foo'. 'help foo.bar' already prints the contents of bar twice.

Is this because Contents.m does not support subfolders? If so, how can we add comments for subfolders?

Comment: It works fine with sub-folders on Mac / R2014b. What MATLAB version are you working on?

Comment: My version is R2016a.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. On R2016a it behaves as expected, with only one section appearing for `+bar`. Is it possible you might have two `+bar` folders on your path, from testing things out?

Comment: @SamRoberts I only have one +bar. I guess if there is another one, the second one would print out different contents...? Do you use Windows or Linux? I use RHEL6 linux.